# How to mute windows phone programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, volume, mute

I want to start working on an app that have basic functionality to mute phone(no sound from any app, ring tone).

Is that possible, I have doubt because MS can take this as security threat.Please let me know from where to start?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programmatically control the entire Phone's volume through an API currently. Only the volume level of sounds from your application may be controlled.

Comment: Any future release in which it is possible, like in 8.1

Comment: THere will be more control, but I wouldn't expect full control. Even Windows 8.1 is more limited in that way, by design, to prevent an inconsistent experience.